# Updating multiple sheets with a userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have created a userform which searched a reference number and then populates the userform fields with entries on the line of that reference number in a "Mastersheet". The thing is that reference may actually be on 3 sheets with the same information and what I am wanting to do, is when I update the information pulled onto the userform to update all 3 sheets. Can you please assist?

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("MasterData")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("X")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("A")
Set ws4 = Worksheets("C")

mysearch = Me.Search.Value

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterData")
        Set searchRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            foundCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = Me.RD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = Me.DD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = Me.PD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = Me.NP.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = Me.Brd.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = Me.Com.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 25).Value = Me.Dt.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 20).Value = Me.PrGp.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 21).Value = Me.Iss.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Me.CVal.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 22).Value = Me.Un.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = Me.Wt.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = Me.Invd.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 26).Value = Me.Sh.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 19).Value = Me.FS.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 18).Value = Me.LN.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 16).Value = Me.Add.Value

    Else

         MsgBox "ID does not exist."

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If I am understanding the question correctly, you want to copy the code which you are currently doing for `Worksheets("MasterData")` and do it again for `Worksheets("X")`, `Worksheets("A")` and `Worksheets("C")`.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the reference is on sheet x or a or c... I have a data entry userform which will qualify the data into 16 difference scenarios and tell it to which of the 4 sheets it needs to go in. sometimes its 2 of the 4 sometimes its 3 of the 4. It will ALWAYS go in the master data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than dimming each sheet, what about just creating a collection for them, using a generic worksheet object, and iterating through the collection? see below.

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetCollection As Collection
Set sheetCollection = New Collection
With sheetCollection
    .Add Worksheets("MasterData"), Worksheets("MasterData").Name
    .Add Worksheets("X"), Worksheets("X").Name
    .Add Worksheets("A"), Worksheets("A").Name
    .Add Worksheets("C"), Worksheets("C").Name
End With

mysearch = Me.Search.Value

For Each ws In sheetCollection
    With ws
        Set searchRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            foundCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = Me.RD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = Me.DD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = Me.PD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = Me.NP.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = Me.Brd.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = Me.Com.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 25).Value = Me.Dt.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 20).Value = Me.PrGp.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 21).Value = Me.Iss.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Me.CVal.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 22).Value = Me.Un.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = Me.Wt.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = Me.Invd.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 26).Value = Me.Sh.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 19).Value = Me.FS.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 18).Value = Me.Ln.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 16).Value = Me.Add.Value
    Else
         MsgBox "ID(" & mysearch & ") does not exist in " & ws.name
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```